# CATIA VBA check parameter existence

Tags: vba, catia

I'm trying to check for the existence of specific parameters in a part and if it does not exist then I want to skip a small section of my code.
This is my current code that works as desired:

```
Dim partDoc As PartDocument
Set partDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Dim ParamV As Parameter
Set ParamV = partDoc.Part.Parameters.Item("ParName")
Dostuffwith ParamV
```

Now I want to add a check before executing the last 2 lines of code, it would become something like this:

```
Dim partDoc As PartDocument
Set partDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Dim ParamV As Parameter

If partDoc.Part.Parameters.Item("ParName") Exists 
then
Set ParamV = partDoc.Part.Parameters.Item("ParName")
Dostuffwith ParamV
End If
```

I tried using

```
On Error goto label1
Set ParamV = partDoc.Part.Parameters.Item("ParName")
Dostuffwith ParamV
label1
```

But this is impossible because On Error needs to end with a Resume or Resume Next. I couldn't find a way to make it Resume after "Dostuffwith ParamV", it will always Resume at the line of code that prompted the error in the first place.

I also tried

```
If not partDoc.Part.Parameters.Item("ParName") is nothing 
Then
Set ParamV = partDoc.Part.Parameters.Item("ParName")
Dostuffwith ParamV
End If
```

But this also gives an error because parameter ParName just doesn't exist.

I don't know what else I can try, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can uso the `On Error Resume Next` clause, and then check for the `Err.Number` to see if any errors occurred:

```
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear 'Clear any previous error messages
Set ParamV = partDoc.Part.Parameters.Item("ParName")
if Err.Number = 0 then
    'TODO Stuff if Parameter Exists
else
    'TODO Stuff if parameter does not Exist
end if
```

Also, you could create a function to test and return the Parameter.

```
Public Function ParameterExist(byref ParameterCollection as Parameters, byval ParameterName as string, Byref OutputParameter as Parameter) as Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    Set OutputParameter = ParameterCollection.Item(ParameterName)
    if Err.Number = 0 then
        ParameterExist = True
    else
        ParameterExist = False
    end if
end function
```

Usage:

```
dim Param as Parameter
If ParameterExist(PartDoc.Part.Parameters, "ParName", Param) then
     'Param will hold the parameter object
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with `On Error Goto <label>` is correct. But you will want to reset the error handler so it will not jump to the label upon another error. You could use:

```
    On Error GoTo label1
    Set ParamV = partDoc.Part.Parameters.Item("ParName")
    On Error GoTo 0        ' reset the error handler upon success
    Dostuffwith ParamV
    GoTo label 2
label1:
    On Error GoTo 0        ' reset the error handler after an error
label2:
```

An alternative is to use the resume method of error handling:

```
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ParamV = partDoc.Part.Parameters.Item("ParName")
    MyErrNumber = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0   ' Reset error handling
    If MyErrNumber <> 0 Then GoTo label1
    Dostuffwith ParamV

label1:
```